# I need to want how to Post/Upload a recorded or selected video to server using binary formate and mp4 type in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, nsurlsession

Hi I just used image picker view to record a video and convert the video formate mov to mp4 and change NSData for posting. But it is not working I get 415 error some times 500 errors. Please check below code for how I implemented. Anybody can guid or help me for this issue.

if I need to check my server side team , they test with postman it is working well when I am implement of below code it is not working if may did any mistakes please guid me thank you

```
-(void)camerabuttonHandlerqas{ 

UIAlertController * picker = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Pick an image using" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init]; 
imagePicker.delegate = self;



UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) { }];

UIAlertAction* takeVideo = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"TakeVideo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;


imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

imagePicker.view.tag = 100; 

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil]; }];
[picker addAction:picture];

[picker addAction:cancel];

picker.view.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor]; 
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

#pragma mark - <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {

videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString* videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test_%d.mp4", [paths objectAtIndex:0],arc4random_uniform(1000)];

NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];


[self convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:videoURL outputURL:outputURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession)


{



switch (exportSession.status) {
     case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
         NSLog(@"status failed");
         break;
     case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:{
         NSLog(@"status success %@ ",videoPath);
         NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary new];

         videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];


         [data setObject:[self generatePostDataForData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoPath]] forKey:@"SelectedvideoURL"];
         imagePickerIsSelected = YES;
         [self postData:data];
         break;

     }

}];


[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }
- (NSData *)generatePostDataForData:(NSData *)uploadData


{    // Generate the post header:

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithCString:"--AaB03x\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[file]\"; 

filename=\"somefile\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    // Get the post header int ASCII format:


NSData *postHeaderData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

// Generate the mutable data variable:


NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength: [postHeaderData length] ];
[postData setData:postHeaderData];


// Add the image:
// Add the closing boundry:





[postData appendData: [@"\r\n--AaB03x--" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

// Return the post data:

return postData;
}







-(void) postData:(NSData *)data

{ 


service = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://1.1.1.1:8080/testing/postapi/photoUpload/uploadVideo?videoName=video_%d&type=mp4",arc4random_uniform(1000)]

delegate = delegateInstance;
service = [service stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: [NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];




NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:service]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];


[request setTimeoutInterval:60];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header

[request setValue:@"mp4/MOV" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];



NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add image data


if (videoData) {
    [body appendData:videoData];
}

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust


[request setHTTPBody:videoData];


// set URL

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];


NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                            if (error) {
                                                NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                            } else {
                                                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);


} }]; [dataTask resume]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

415 error media type error check your server data type on which u r storing NSDATA.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution that code is absolutely right and no need to change media type to mp4 if server side accept .mov type and please discuss with server side then have to change content type, and take file like as a one data then its working for me

Thank you.